# Finding documents lacking a field in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to ES and currently evaluating how it would work for us as a backend for storing log data/events. One of the requirements is to bulk update all indexed events and, e.g. add a field.

I looked at the query DSL but I can't find an example for a query that would retrieve all docs **which do NOT contain** a certain field. The DSL is very expressive when it comes to describing values, but not fieldnames and field existence.

Maybe this is an unusual usecase for typical ES users but I already ran into a real need for it when playing with the ElasticSearch ELK stack. When I inserted data into ES which had the wrong format for Kibana, I got loads of exceptions. Now I wanted to correct the format but I can't retrieve the corrupted documents. Is there a way?

Comment: ¨this might be what you're looking for http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-not-filter.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to  use the "[exists](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-filter.html)" filter  in conjunction with the "[not](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-not-filter.html)" filter mentioned  above by @touchpad or simply the "[missing](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-missing-filter.html)" filter

```
  {
   "filter": {
      "not": {
         "exists": {
            "field": <field_name>
         }
      }
   }
}
```